# Add disk space to vagrant virtual box

Tags: disk

I have a macOS and want to increase vagrant disk size by 50gb, how can I do this with terminal and vagrant 2.3.2

Comment: To clarify ... you're running macOS and want to expand a vagrant virtual image that runs inside a virtual box instance? 

Comment: yes I have tried the virtual box settings, the size increases but only half of what I should see is shown.

Comment: So far, based on every word that exists in the question and the reply comment, I'm not seeing anything that is related to Ubuntu. Could you [edit] your question to include: (0) the version of Ubuntu that you're running (1) the exact steps that you followed (2) the results that you're seeing. With this, it may be feasible to offer an answer, but *specifics* will be required.